# How to make these triangles into quads

Tags: topology

I have these triangles I need to make into quads, I'm confused how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "triangles", there's only one, the rest showing are quads (and two n-gons).  That having been said, this is one of the standard ways to change a tri like that to a quad:

[image]

That won't be the best topology for all circumstances, but without anything else to go on?  That's how I'd do it.  If you wanted all-quads:

[image]

That makes two E-poles or 5-poles, indicated by the green arrows.  Another potential all-quads solution would be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked well on my mesh, simple thing I didn't even think off.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, I understand you right. If you want to make your topology look like this:
[image: Final result]

you can just merge vertices of triangles at center (m key -> at center) and you will get something like this:
[image: Intermediate part]
I suppose you should do it for every place where you have that pairs of vertices.